# Store information about a text selection on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to highlight a range of text from an html page and get the highlighted position to then use to store comments.

**My problem**

I have an article page which allows the user to highlight a selection of text and add a comment. I have it to a point where I can position a UI box to the right of the selected text to enter a comment (think google docs).

I need to store information about the selected text so that I can link it to any comments. Ideally I would just store the selected text and then scan the content for that selection. This has a major flaw: what if two or more copies of the same text selection occur in the content.

The content itself is HTML stored in a DB.

For example a selection of the following paragraph has been highlighted (bold selection). I need to store information about the selection to be able to find it in the future:

"Efficiently revolutionize interoperable human capital via viral niches. Holisticly seize world-class potentialities through worldwide communities. Objectively embrace **multidisciplinary niches** for parallel paradigms. Professionally."

**What I've done so far**

Using the `getBoundingClientRect()` of the text selection `range` I can get the distance from the top of the page. Although useful for positioning the UI comment box I don't think this will help me to link comments to their selected text.

I can get the selected text from `window.getSelection()` but there could be multiple occurrences.

I'd like to NOT modify the content. i.e wrap the selection in a `span` or similar if I can help it as if a comment is removed it might be tricky to them remove the markup.

Answer (score 1):

window.getSelection gives you an object with much more than just the text. You could store the whole object, you'd have pretty much all the information you need.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Normally anchorNode (on which you can apply parentNode to get the section in which the selection has begun) and startOffset should be unique for all your selections and you can target exactly the characters that have been selected without relying on text content.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to have the comments set on offsets in your text (i.e. character #100 to character #150).

You'll have to resolve the diffs when people edit your document (and if they don't, all the better!), so if someone adds 10 characters before the part where the comment was placed, the comment now points to 110-160.

Comment: The only problem with this method is that `startOffset` and `endOffset` from the range are as part of a section. i.e a paragraph will be a section but also if a paragraph contains a link in the middle then it splits the paragraph into two sections and so `startOffset` could be 0 but from the 2nd section of the 2nd paragraph. Although there's no way to know which sections.

Comment: It looks like the offsets provided `getRangeAt(0)` are relative to the 'section' not the whole text. If I highlight the first word of the second paragraph the `startOffset` is 0.

Comment: @iamjonesy In that case, you just need to add that local offset to the offset of the whole section from the beginning of the text, a calculation you only need to do once.